# What is the correct way to have a component receive a class as an input, while also applying its own classes?

Tags: angular

Imagine I have a component that applies certain values to the `class` attribute of its host element, based on certain run-time conditions.

For example, take this TextBox component, which applies class values based on the state of readonly and disabled inputs passed in to it:

```
class TextBoxComponent {
  @HostBinding("class.readonly") @Input() public readonly = false;
  @HostBinding("class.disabled") @Input() public disabled = false;
}
```

Suppose I want to also pass in arbitrary class values from the container, by setting the `class` attribute.

For example, say I want to pass in a `pull-right` class for positioning:

```
<text-box [disabled]="false" [readonly]="false" class="pull-right"></text-box>
```

What's the most correct way to do this in Angular? Both from the consumer's point of view and coding it to work correctly within the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be an official way (at least from examining the docs) I ended up doing the simplest thing I could think of.

On my component, I declare my @Inputs(), including one named 'class':

```
@Input() color: string;
@Input() size: string;
@Input() class: string;
```

Then I use HostBinding with a getter, which joins them all together:

```
@HostBinding("class")
private get classes() {
  return [this.color, this.size, this.class].join(" ");
}
```

Now I can pass any of these three inputs into my component:

```
<app-label color="blue" class="left"></app-label>
```

And it renders to the DOM with the classes on the component's element:

```
<app-label _ngcontent-c0="" class="blue 50px myClass" color="blue" size="50px" _nghost-c1="" ng-reflect-color="blue" ng-reflect-size="50px" ng-reflect-class="myClass"></app-label>
```

Answer (score 0):

My take is [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

for instance

```
<text-box [disabled]="false" [readonly]="false" 
[ngClass]="{'pull-right':pullRightCondition, <etc...>}></text-box>
```

I think you can apply any given class you recive in an input as well like this:

```
TS:
@Input() myInputClassInString: String;
HTML:
[ngClass]="myInputClassInString"
```

Comment: Your solution implies to give a string as a `ngClass` attribute, meaning you would have to write an object, then pass it as a string, meaning you would have to escape every quote. Not very convenient. (by the way, it is `[ngClass]="'{\'pull-right\':pullRightCondition, <etc...>}'`)

Answer (score 0):

Well yo ucould simply use a different selector and a diffrent tag !

```js
@Component({
  selector: '[text-box]',
  ...
})
```

In your HTML

```
<div text-box [disabled]="false" [readonly]="false" class="pull-right"></div>
```

This way, you directly set the class of your component, and you get rid of the annoying surrounding tag Angular uses to encapsulate your components.